# Why does vinegar made from wine contain only about half as much acid as the original alcohol?

Tags: bacteriology, fermentation, food-chemistry

It is my understanding that the fermenting bacteria process the alcohol into acetic acid. But why is it about half the percentage of volume? For example table wine is often 12% ethanol, but vinegar is generally about 5% acetic acid.

Comment: Can you add sources to your claims? As a hunch, enzymes help to swiftly establish equilibria. Enzymes don't push the equalibrium to an end product. Further, the end product may be toxic. Take the fermentation processing during beer brewing - there's a substantial amount of sugar left after the beer is ready. Alcohol is toxic to yeast.

Comment: Not really; i take this claim as a fact of everyday life. Both alcohol and acedic acid contents are indicated on the bottles. German language Wikipedia has a list of aciditys for various types of wine (those alkohol contents are not indicated), but i guess that is no scientific source:  https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essig#G%C3%A4rungsessige

Comment: Yep, makes sense. +1

Comment: What evidence have you that the wine used for wine vinegar contains 12% alcohol? I would have thought it would more likely be lower alcohol wine made from poorer grapes with a lower must weight (content of natural grape sugar). It is unlikely to bear much relationship to commercial table wines, which are often chaptalized in order to reach the EU minimum alcohol level.

Comment: That the acetic acid always has 5% has the simple reason that it is diluted to this concentration.

Comment: @Chris — Actually it's generally 6% in the EU, but you're right. I found an interesting paper on [sherry vinegar production](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jf020093z), which starts with 13% ethanol and ends up as over 11% acetic acid + 1.5% ethanol. Also a general [article](http://www.madehow.com/Volume-7/Vinegar.html) about industrial production of vinegar which explicitly states that it is diluted to 5-6%.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it turns out this question has a trivial answer that is nothing to do with biology.

Comment: @Chris: And further, that it is diluted to that concentration because that's what tastes good.  Though vinegars do vary in acetic acid concentration.  To high a concentration can be hazardous, though.

Comment: @David That article states that it is diluted in case the "The generator method" is used, which does'nt start with wine.  Do you have any reference for wine vinegar -not vinegar 'essence'-  usually being diluted?

Comment: @HannesH — No, but people don't usually advertise that they water their beer (or whisky, unless you buy cask strength and then water it yourself). I leave you to join the dots.

Comment: As regards Sherry vinegar (which I mentioned is from sherry at 13% ethanol (less than normal sherry, incidentally), an internet search suggests 7% acetic acid is a more normal final concentration. That would suggest to me that it is watered down from 11%.

Comment: Would it? Would'nt it suggest that my question is still valid? - pending any reference to watering as the standart practice, ofcourse.

Comment: @Chris Besides that it isn't always 5%, could you reference why you think that vinagar from wine -not "essence"- is diluted?